# Update XAML Binding after a property changes

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-8.1, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM light on a Windows 8.1 Store app. I have a view model that has several properties on it that have no setters (their value is derived from a different property). Here is part of my ViewModel:

```
public float TotalAmount
{
    get
    {
        if (!LineItems.Any())
            return 0.0f;

        return SubTotal + TotalFees - TotalDiscounts;

    }
}

public float SubTotal
{
    get
    {
        return !LineItems.Any() ? 0.0f : LineItems.Select(i => i.Price.Amount).Sum();
    }
}

public float TotalFees
{
    get
    {
        return !Fees.Any() ? 0.0f : Fees.Select(f => f.Amount).Sum();
    }
}

public float TotalDiscounts
{
    get
    {
        return !Discounts.Any() ? 0.0f : Discounts.Select(d => d.Amount).Sum();
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<Discount> Discounts { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<Fee> Fees { get; set; } 

public Customer Customer { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<OrderLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
```

In the XAML, I bind to each of these properties, and want to update them when an Item is added to LineItems.

Here is the relevant part of the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="SubTotal:" Style="{StaticResource OrderDetailsLabel}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource OrderDetailsValue}"
                Text="{Binding SubTotal, Converter={StaticResource MoneyConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Fees:" Style="{StaticResource OrderDetailsLabel}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource OrderDetailsValue}" Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding TotalFees, Converter={StaticResource MoneyConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Discounts:" Style="{StaticResource OrderDetailsLabel}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource OrderDetailsValue}" Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding TotalDiscounts, Converter={StaticResource MoneyConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="Order Total:" Style="{StaticResource OrderDetailsLabel}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource OrderDetailsValue}" Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding TotalAmount, Converter={StaticResource MoneyConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

My Binding to the LineItems is working as expected, but the fields that are populated by doing math on the line items are not.

Line Item Binding functioning as expected:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LineItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                ....
```

How can I get SubTotal, Total, etc. to update when LineItems changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by raising the OnPropertyChanged event on in the handler for my AddLineItems message:

```
    public NewOrderViewModel()
    {
        //Subscribe to messages
        MessengerInstance.Register<OrderItemAdded>(this, o => AddOrderItem(o.LineItem));
        MessengerInstance.Register<SelectedCustomer>(this, c => Customer = c.Customer);

        Discounts = new ObservableCollection<Discount>();
        Fees = new ObservableCollection<Fee>();
        LineItems = new ObservableCollection<OrderLineItem>();

    }

    private void AddOrderItem(OrderLineItem lineItem)
    {
        //add Line Item to collection
        LineItems.Add(lineItem);

        //Raise events for properties derived from collection
        RaisePropertyChanged("TotalAmount");
        RaisePropertyChanged("SubTotal");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

Register the `ObservableCollection<T>.CollectionChanged` event for each of those collection.  Since your desired properties are based on some calculation of the collection.

On event fire Raise the OnPropertyChanged on those properties.

---

Example how to raise the OnPropertyChanged/inotifypropertychanged

[MSDN: inotifypropertychanged Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in your constructor:

```
LineItems.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
{
   RaisePropertyChanged("SubTotal");
   RaisePropertyChanged("TotalFees");
   RaisePropertyChanged("TotalDiscounts");
}
```

assuming your ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and has a 'RaisePropertyChanged' method that raises the PropertyChanged event (e.g. You're using MVVM-Light's ViewModelBase as your baseclass).